# How do i make an object collide with a color?

Tags: libgdx

I'm making my very first game with libgdx, and it involves making levels with many right angles, very much like a maze. All I know how to make a collision is to make an invisible rectangle on each wall that collides with the player, but with so many walls this is an irrational solution, to make a rectangle for every single wall.

Since all the walls and edges will be black, is there a way I can make it so the player collides with anything the color black? That would be an incredible help.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking the time to learn how to use tile maps. Using tiles should help you accomplish what you want and there's already a bunch of tutorials on this, a few of them listed below.

[Tile maps on the libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps)

[A tutorial on tile maps from gamesfromscratch.com](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/04/16/LibGDX-Tutorial-11-Tiled-Maps-Part-1-Simple-Orthogonal-Maps.aspx)

[A YouTube tutorial on tile maps, which also covers collision detection](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0qmqSBhOtqYRjzWtUCWylb)

The tutorials I link may not apply exactly to your case, but they should hopefully point you in the right direction.